# How to use the ImageGrab.grab().load() function or any other function to get pixel updates?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, python-imaging-library, pixel

I have been trying to check if a pixel on the screen is changing. What do I need to do?

I have surfed the internet for a long time with no success. I have experimented with the code given on the net, and found out that my code is only giving data from the screen that was open when the code was run. ie, if the screen was white when the code was run, it will read pixels from the white screen, even though the screen color already changed.

```py
from PIL import ImageGrab
px=ImageGrab.grab().load()
m=px[613,296]
print(m)
while 1:
    if m!=px[613,296]:
        m=px[613,296]
        print(m)
```

I ran the code and started a video, I expected the values to keep changing but all I got was **(255,255,255)** (the white screen of the idle) I also tried to change the screen manually.

I tried runing the code without console and print the output without the while loop in a text file, I got correct values.But the task I need to complete needs to run the code several times to check if pixel updates. How should I accomplish this?

Comment: The most likely thing is that you have the coordinates the wrong way around. Try running your video **full-screen** so that the entire screen is changing, or try printing `px.mean()` continuously and see if the value changes as the video gets lighter/darker.

Comment: I am sure my coordinates are correct. I have mentioned that I have tried changing the RGB values at that coordinates manually, by moving windows and pictures over it. I tried running your code but it says that px has no attribute mean. I have tried the same code with pyautogui, it works fine, but it is too slow for my needs, it take approx. 0.8secs to access a pixel.

Comment: If you are expecting the value to change, you'll need to move the `grab()` **inside** your `while` loop, surely?

Comment: I don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import ImageGrab

while True:
   px=ImageGrab.grab().load()
   m=px[613,296]
   print(m)
```

---

I think it will be faster if you just grab one pixel though by specifying a bounding box like this so you only grab one pixel:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import ImageGrab

while True:
   screen=ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(613,296,614,297))
   px = screen.load()
   m=px[0,0]
   print(m,screen.size)
```