# how to get pixel color on screen in python

Tags: python, image

I'm really really beginning/nooby in this and i'm trying to detect the color green on my screen and when it shows up click the mouse button. im also using sublime text 2 but I also have idle.

```
    import ImageGrab
    import time
    time.clock()
    image = ImageGrab.grab()
    for y in range(0, 100, 10):
        for x in range(0, 100, 10):
            color = image.getpixel((x, y))
    print(time.clock())
```

i tried this but it just gives me this "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ImageGrab'"
I have been scouring the internet for littarl hours and i just cant find any tutorials that help with installing pillow. this is ridiculously complicated and im about to give up

Comment: Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800458/quickly-getting-the-color-of-some-pixels-on-the-screen-in-python-on-windows-7

Comment: yeah ive seen that post but every time i try it it says "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ImageGrab'"

Comment: Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/55516307/2836621

Comment: i tryed all that and i still get module not found

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
import ImageGrab
```

use

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
```

You should have PIL already installed. PIL is the "Python Image Library" and can be downloaded from https://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/

Note that PIL is quite old and seems to be only available for Python 2.x (and even older).
You could also use the Python package Pillow instead, which is a fork of PIL. This can be installed using `pip install Pillow` in (recent versions of) Python 2 as well as 3.